# Can't connect with Mongo-Spark Connector using Mongo in Authentication mode

Tags: mongodb, authentication, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

I'm trying to run a spark-submit job, using a MongoDB instance on a remote machine, via the Mongo-Spark Connector.

When I initiate the mongod service **without** the `--auth` flag, and run the `spark-submit` command like this:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://10.0.3.155:7077 \
                   --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://10.0.3.156/test.coll?readPreference=primaryPreferred" \
                   --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://10.0.3.156/test.coll" \
                   --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0 \
                   app1.py
```

Everything works like a charm.

But when I run the mongod service **with** the `--auth` flag, and run the `spark-submit` like that:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://10.0.3.155:7077 \
                   --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://admin:pass@10.0.3.156/test.coll?readPreference=primaryPreferred" \
                   --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://admin:pass@10.0.3.156/test.coll" \
                   --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0 \
                   app1.py
```

I get these errors:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.save. : com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=10.0.3.156:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='admin', source='test', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server 10.0.3.156:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "code" : 18, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." }}}]
at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:369)
at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:101)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getWriteConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:68)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:158)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:133)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:128)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:118)
at com.mongodb.operation.DropCollectionOperation.execute(DropCollectionOperation.java:54)
at com.mongodb.operation.DropCollectionOperation.execute(DropCollectionOperation.java:39)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:781)
at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:764)
at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.drop(MongoCollectionImpl.java:419)
at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource$$anonfun$createRelation$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:89)
at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource$$anonfun$createRelation$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:89)
at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withCollectionDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:186)
at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withCollectionDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:184)
at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:171)
at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:171)
at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withMongoClientDo(MongoConnector.scala:154)
at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withDatabaseDo(MongoConnector.scala:171)
at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withCollectionDo(MongoConnector.scala:184)
at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:518)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've checked the credentials and roles, and all is fine. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure the `authSource` query parameter in your Connection String, otherwise the supplied database (test) will be used:

```
spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://10.0.3.156/test.coll?authSource=admin&readPreference=primaryPreferred
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it was a credential issue after all.
The thing is that I tried to connect to `test` DB, while the credentials I entered were for the `admin` DB.

That's it.